# Not able to integrate Jetpack compose getting error ( build_1azsqk04fv9sx4ykpvygn8par.android() )

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

- I Am trying to integrate Jetpack compose
- In a sample project, I am able to integrate
- In our main project has a lot of legacy code. I am not able to
  integrate
- I have minSdk = 22

**Error**:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> No signature of method: build_1azsqk04fv9sx4ykpvygn8par.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_1azsqk04fv9sx4ykpvygn8par$_run_closure7) values: [build_1azsqk04fv9sx4ykpvygn8par$_run_closure7@56b29188]

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
```

***Has anyone faced this and how to resolve this?***

Comment: I once faced something similar because there was a syntax error in `build.gradle` file - I placed a config into wrong brackets or something like that.

Comment: Can you share the dependency line that you wrote?